# FFmpeg to RTMP streaming stucks after few seconds

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

I'm trying to stream to online service via FFmpeg. All my test commands works fine with restream.io preview and with local rtmp server viewer. My OBS setup works fine too (same resolution, server and key). Only when I'm about to start ffmpeg stream from my command line it stucks after few seconds.

My test command:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 \
   -i noise.mov \
   -c:v libx264 c:a aac \
   -f flv 'rtmps://live-upload******'
```

With `-debug pict` after some progress with input files and rtmp handshaking I can see this:

```
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000008
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 10 times
[h264 @ 0x7ff12001da00] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 5 times
[h264 @ 0x7ff12001e000] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 10 times
[h264 @ 0x7ff12001e600] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 5 times
[h264 @ 0x7ff12001ec00] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 8 times
[h264 @ 0x7ff12001ac00] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 5 times
[h264 @ 0x7ff12001da00] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 5 times
[h264 @ 0x7ff12001e000] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
[libx264 @ 0x7ff120802400] frame=   0 QP=20.00 NAL=3 Slice:I Poc:0   I:3600 P:0    SKIP:0    size=216266 bytes
[h264 @ 0x7ff12001e600] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
[libx264 @ 0x7ff120802400] frame=   1 QP=31.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:2   I:287  P:3267 SKIP:46   size=48597 bytes
[h264 @ 0x7ff12001ec00] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
[libx264 @ 0x7ff120802400] frame=   2 QP=30.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:4   I:710  P:2888 SKIP:2    size=79226 bytes
```

...and that's it.

The same command works fine with any other online service except this one. What I can do to debug it? Works fine with OBS, but won't with `ffmpeg` command. `noise.mov` — 720×1280px mov file.

Full log:

```
iMac:Desktop 350d$ ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -i noise.mov -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -c:a aac -f flv -debug pict 'rtmps://live-upload.*******' 
ffmpeg version N-96521-g5e62100152-tessus  https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay
  libavutil      56. 38.100 / 56. 38.100
  libavcodec     58. 67.100 / 58. 67.100
  libavformat    58. 36.100 / 58. 36.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 71.100 /  7. 71.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
 matched as AVOption 'debug' with argument 'pict'.
Reading option 'rtmps://live-upload.************' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url /Users/350d/Desktop/noise.mov.
Applying option stream_loop (set number of times input stream shall be looped) with argument -1.
Applying option re (read input at native frame rate) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: /Users/350d/Desktop/noise.mov.
[NULL @ 0x7fb1e5000000] Opening '/Users/350d/Desktop/noise.mov' for reading
[file @ 0x7fb1e4c01700] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb1e5000000] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 probed with size=2048 and score=100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb1e5000000] ISO: File Type Major Brand: qt  
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb1e5000000] Unknown dref type 0x73696c61 size 12
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb1e5000000] Processing st: 0, edit list 0 - media time: 2112, duration: 160230
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb1e5000000] drop a frame at curr_cts: 0 @ 0
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb1e5000000] drop a frame at curr_cts: 1024 @ 1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb1e5000000] skip 64 audio samples from curr_cts: 2048
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb1e5000000] Unknown dref type 0x73696c61 size 12
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb1e5000000] Shifting DTS by 100 because of negative CTTS.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb1e5000000] Processing st: 1, edit list 0 - media time: 0, duration: 10900
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb1e5000000] stts: 0 ctts: 0, ctts_index: 0, ctts_count: 109
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb1e5000000] stts: 100 ctts: 100, ctts_index: 1, ctts_count: 109
....
....
....
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb1e5000000] stts: 10800 ctts: 0, ctts_index: 108, ctts_count: 109
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb1e5000000] Setting codecpar->delay to 1 for stream st: 1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb1e5000000] Unknown dref type 0x73696c61 size 12
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb1e5000000] Processing st: 2, edit list 0 - media time: 0, duration: 10900
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb1e5000000] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 3397542 bytes read:70076 seeks:3 nb_streams:3
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5806a00] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5806a00] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb1e5000000] demuxer injecting skip 2112 / discard 0
[aac @ 0x7fb1e5010c00] skip 2112 / discard 0 samples due to side data
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5806a00] nal_unit_type: 6(SEI), nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5806a00] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5806a00] Format yuv420p chosen by get_format().
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5806a00] Reinit context to 720x1280, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5806a00] no picture 
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb1e5000000] All info found
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb1e5000000] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 200654 bytes read:270218 seeks:4 frames:45
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/350d/Desktop/noise.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2020-01-27T09:49:16.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.displayname: STREAM
    com.apple.quicktime.title: STREAM
  Duration: 00:00:03.63, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7480 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und), 44, 1/44100: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 101 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-01-27T09:49:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
    Stream #0:1(und), 1, 1/3000: Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive, left), 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 0/1, 7328 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 3k tbn, 6k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-01-27T09:49:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : H.264
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:2(und), 0, 1/3000: Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0/1, 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-01-27T09:49:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Time Code
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url rtmps://live-upload.*************.
Applying option c:v (codec name) with argument libx264.
Applying option c:a (codec name) with argument aac.
Applying option f (force format) with argument flv.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: rtmps://live-upload.********************.
[rtmps @ 0x7fb1e4c04a00] No default whitelist set
[tls @ 0x7fb1e4c04880] No default whitelist set
[tcp @ 0x7fb1e4c04940] No default whitelist set
[tcp @ 0x7fb1e4c04940] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 0x7fb1e4c04940] Address ***** port 443
[tcp @ 0x7fb1e4c04940] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 0x7fb1e4c04940] Address ***** port 443
[tcp @ 0x7fb1e4c04940] Starting connection attempt to ***** port 443
[tcp @ 0x7fb1e4c04940] Successfully connected to ***** port 443
[rtmps @ 0x7fb1e4c04a00] Handshaking...
[rtmps @ 0x7fb1e4c04a00] Type answer 3
[rtmps @ 0x7fb1e4c04a00] Server version 1.0.5.4
[rtmps @ 0x7fb1e4c04a00] Proto = rtmps, path = /rtmp/**************, app = rtmp, fname = *****************
[rtmps @ 0x7fb1e4c04a00] Window acknowledgement size = 5000000
[rtmps @ 0x7fb1e4c04a00] Max sent, unacked = 5000000
[rtmps @ 0x7fb1e4c04a00] New incoming chunk size = 4096
[rtmps @ 0x7fb1e4c04a00] Releasing stream...
[rtmps @ 0x7fb1e4c04a00] FCPublish stream...
[rtmps @ 0x7fb1e4c04a00] Creating stream...
[rtmps @ 0x7fb1e4c04a00] Sending publish command for '********************'
Successfully opened the file.
detected 4 logical cores
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5035400] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5035400] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[aac @ 0x7fb1e5011800] skip 2112 / discard 0 samples due to side data
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 1 times
[aac @ 0x7fb1e5011800] skip 64/1024 samples
[graph_1_in_0_0 @ 0x7fb1e4e05540] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/44100'
[graph_1_in_0_0 @ 0x7fb1e4e05540] Setting 'sample_rate' to value '44100'
[graph_1_in_0_0 @ 0x7fb1e4e05540] Setting 'sample_fmt' to value 'fltp'
[graph_1_in_0_0 @ 0x7fb1e4e05540] Setting 'channel_layout' to value '0x3'
[graph_1_in_0_0 @ 0x7fb1e4e05540] tb:1/44100 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:44100 chlayout:0x3
[format_out_0_1 @ 0x7fb1e4e03f00] Setting 'sample_fmts' to value 'fltp'
[format_out_0_1 @ 0x7fb1e4e03f00] Setting 'sample_rates' to value '96000|88200|64000|48000|44100|32000|24000|22050|16000|12000|11025|8000|7350'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fb1e4d10940] query_formats: 4 queried, 9 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 197507 times
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 190577 times
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5035400] nal_unit_type: 6(SEI), nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5035400] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5035400] Format yuv420p chosen by get_format().
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5035400] Reinit context to 720x1280, pix_fmt: yuv420p
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 436 times
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5035400] no picture 
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 9068 times
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 8658 times
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e580ae00] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 8151 times
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5807600] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 18758 times
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5807c00] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 8906 times
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5821c00] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 10004 times
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5035400] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x7fb1e4d13080] Setting 'video_size' to value '720x1280'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x7fb1e4d13080] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value '0'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x7fb1e4d13080] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/3000'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x7fb1e4d13080] Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '1/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x7fb1e4d13080] Setting 'frame_rate' to value '30/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 0x7fb1e4d13080] w:720 h:1280 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/3000 fr:30/1 sar:1/1
[format @ 0x7fb1e4d12f00] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'yuv420p|yuvj420p|yuv422p|yuvj422p|yuv444p|yuvj444p|nv12|nv16|nv21|yuv420p10le|yuv422p10le|yuv444p10le|nv20le|gray|gray10le'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fb1e4f0a5c0] query_formats: 4 queried, 3 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
[libx264 @ 0x7fb1e5015600] using mv_range_thread = 104
[libx264 @ 0x7fb1e5015600] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7fb1e5015600] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7fb1e5015600] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7fb1e5015600] 264 - core 159 r2991 1771b55 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
[flv @ 0x7fb1e5014400] Ignoring metadata for framerate
[flv @ 0x7fb1e5014400] Ignoring metadata for width
[flv @ 0x7fb1e5014400] Ignoring metadata for height
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmps://live-upload.***********************************':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf58.36.100
    com.apple.quicktime.displayname: IG STREAM
    com.apple.quicktime.title: IG STREAM
    framerate       : 30
    width           : 720
    height          : 1280
    title           : USERNAME
    creation_time   : 2020-01-27T09:49:16.000000Z
    Stream #0:0(und), 0, 1/1000: Video: h264 (libx264), 1 reference frame ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p(left), 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 0/1, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-01-27T09:49:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
      encoder         : Lavc58.67.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1(und), 0, 1/1000: Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, delay 1024, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-01-27T09:49:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      encoder         : Lavc58.67.100 aac
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000008
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 10 times
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e580ae00] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 5 times
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5807600] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 10 times
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5807c00] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 3 times
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5821c00] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 10 times
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5035400] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 5 times
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e580ae00] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 5 times
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5807600] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
[libx264 @ 0x7fb1e5015600] frame=   0 QP=20.00 NAL=3 Slice:I Poc:0   I:3600 P:0    SKIP:0    size=216266 bytes
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5807c00] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
[libx264 @ 0x7fb1e5015600] frame=   1 QP=31.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:2   I:287  P:3267 SKIP:46   size=48597 bytes
[h264 @ 0x7fb1e5821c00] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 0
[libx264 @ 0x7fb1e5015600] frame=   2 QP=30.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:4   I:710  P:2888 SKIP:2    size=79226 bytes
^C[tls @ 0x7fb1e4c04880] IO Error: -9806
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Input/output error
[libx264 @ 0x7fb1e5015600] frame=   3 QP=30.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:6   I:355  P:3245 SKIP:0    size=82386 bytes
```

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @Gyan post updated!

Comment: Could be a known issue, I would bump this ticket: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5088